# Can I use Swift on the back end of an API?

Tags: swift, rest, api-design, chess

I am wanting to create a chess engine. I am most familiar with Swift, and super high-performance isn't all that important to me (otherwise I'd likely learn and write it in C++). I need my engine to take in a chess position [in an FEN formatted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) string, which would look something like this: `rnbqkbnr/pp1ppppp/8/2p5/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R b KQkq - 1 2`. It would then process the position and spit out a move in [algebraic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)), like `Nxd4`.

These specifics aren't all that important, however, as I can program all of this in Swift. What I am wondering is how one would create an API with swift to do this. That is, the url encoded FEN position is passed a parameter to the API like so: `https://www.mywebsite.com/chessEngine?position=rnbqkbnr%2Fpp1ppppp%2F8%2F2p5%2F4P3%2F5N2%2FPPPP1PPP%2FRNBQKB1R%20b%20KQkq%20-%201%202`

The Swift code would then process this position on the backend, and the response would be something like:

```
{status:"success",recommendedMove:"Nxd4",moveTime:"12.34"}
```

Is it even possible to have Swift code process on the back end? My API development experience is limited to taking parameters as url parameters, making an SQL query, and then echoing the query response as a JSON.

**See also:** https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/26489/creating-chess-engine-machine-learning-vs-traditional-engine

Comment: I haven't done any back end development with Swift, but I've tinkered with it a bit. You may find this post helpful. https://www.raywenderlich.com/1323930-vapor-vs-kitura-choosing-a-server-side-swift-framework

Comment: Thanks a ton @Adrian, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Although I haven't built a full site/API with Swift, I know that [Vapor](http://vapor.codes) uses itself to host its website, and my (albeit limited) experience with it suggests that it would be a good pick. That said, you could also use [Kitura](https://www.kitura.io) or [Perfect](https://perfect.org) — try looking up a comparison between them.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome, I'll check out Vapor and get back to you. Perfect seems to rank well on google searches, but Vapor looks a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check [Hummingbird](https://github.com/hummingbird-project/hummingbird) as well. It's under active development like **Vapor**. Kitura is from IBM, but they already abandoned the project and Perfect is not active anymore too.